# C++ statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Tags: c++

Ok It's prolly sth really basic but I give up. I just wanted to check answer for a question:
Is compilator gonna protest?

```
cell->unregister();
cell.erase();
```

So I wrote a simplest script in c++ to check:

```
/*
* main.cpp
*
 *  Created on: Aug 7, 2014
 *      Author: luke
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class abs
{
    int a,b;

public:
    void unregister(){
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
    void erase(){
        a = 2;
        b = 0;
    }
    abs(int c,int d);
};
abs::abs(int c,int d){
    a = c;
    b = d;
}
int main () {
    abs obj(4, 2);

    obj->unregister();
    obj.erase();
}
```

The errors I get are:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type statement cannot resolve
>   address of overloaded function    main.cpp    /testing    line 32 C/C++ Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Method 'unregister' could not
>   be resolved   main.cpp    /testing    line 34 Semantic Error
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Method 'erase' could not be
>   resolved  main.cpp    /testing    line 35 Semantic Error
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type make: *** [main.o] Error
>   1 testing         C/C++ Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type expected ‘;’ before
>   ‘obj’ main.cpp    /testing    line 32 C/C++ Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type ‘obj’ was not declared in this
>   scope main.cpp    /testing    line 34 C/C++ Problem

Comment: Why `->unregister()` and not `.unregister()` ? The `->` syntax is not valid here.

Comment: `obj->unregister()` is not correct because obj is not a pointer. You should replace with `obj.unregister()`. Is this the problem ?

Comment: yes, the compilator doth protest, and the errors you received are evidence of that. [See it live](http://ideone.com/9eCSqS) on an online compiler for yet more evidence if you don't believe your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

**1)** `abs` is a [C standard function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/), you included it in your program when you `#include <cstdlib>`. Your class `abs` has a name conflicting with this function.

**2)** `obj->unregister` should be `obj.unregister()`, since `obj` is an object, not a pointer.

---

**Solution:**

- Choose another name for your class `abs`
- Or declare it in a `namespace` of yours.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9a526c0505ba8ea)

Comment: Yeah thanks mate ! I just typed random letters for class name, it didn't occur to me that it maybe reserved... Damn wasted quite a lot time on this one :P but I guess it's still a lesson for me :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be `obj.unregister();` as obj is an actual object not a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler should protest this line:

```
obj->unregister();
```

The '->' operator is used with pointers, and here it is not. It should be:

```
obj.unregister();
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj` is not a pointer, so the `->` operator won't work on it. Use `.` instead:

```
obj->unregister();
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the compiler does protest.
`->` would not work here. `obj->unregister();` is a shorthand for `(*obj).unregister();`
It works when the object is initialized on the heap, link this

```
abs1 * obj = new abs1(4, 2);
obj->unregister(); // obj.unregister(); will not work
obj->erase();
```

You initialized the object on stack; so -> will not work and only "." will work:

```
abs1 obj(4, 2);
obj.unregister(); // obj->unregister(); will not work
obj.erase();
```

**Update**: I updated the examples to correct the problem of `abs` using the same name as the system function, pointed out in other answers.

Comment: Yep, you are right. But the thing is my goal was to simply verify if obj->unregister(); will work or not. The problem was that I couldn't do it because I used the abs for class name, and couldn't initialize the object. So now that I changed class name to abc, it worked and I realized that the obj->unregister(); doesn't work :) so I have my answer . I know I could just google for it but I prefer to check things like this "manually", helps me remember better.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 problems in the main :

1. access to a pointer
2. abs is a C function then you need to indicate that it is a class (better to rename it)

This will fix both :

```
int main () {
    class abs obj(4, 2);

    obj.unregister();
    obj.erase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program has two errors.
First of all it is a bad idea to name a class the same way as the name of a function.
You included header `<cstdlib>` that contains the declaration of standard C function `abs`.This function name hides the class abs.
To resolve the problem you have to use elaborated class name in statement

```
abs obj(4, 2);
```

That is you have to write

```
class abs obj(4, 2);
```

The second error is using member access operator `->` instead of . That is you have to write

```
obj.unregister();
```

instead of

```
obj->unregister();
```